# How can I safely put a plug on an old furnace motor that has just two wires

Tags: furnace

My Old furnace motor has just 2 wires, Black and white. How can I safely put a plug on it to use it? I want it to power a chicken plucker.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't just attach a plug directly to the leads coming off a motor.

Mount the motor in or to the rest of the machine, and assuming it's metal, this establishes a grounding bond between them. You can then mount a small junction box, and terminate the wires from the motor in there. Be sure there is continuity from the motor housing to the junction box -- it may be necessary to add a ground wire for this purpose, especially if the motor itself has a ground lug. Grounding all the metal parts of the machine is important for safety. If there is a short, without a ground, anyone that touches an energized metal part will be electrocuted. With a ground, the electricity will follow the path of least resistance (the ground conductor, instead of the human touching it) and in most cases, enough current will flow that within milliseconds the upstream fuse/breaker will trip and the power will shut off.

To add a plug, use some SJO-type wire (that has two conductors plus ground) and connect the ground to the junction box (thus grounding the junction box, housing, and motor housing), and make the connection to hot/neutral in the junction box as well. Your connections should be either wire nuts or a terminal strip of sorts. Be sure to use a strain-relief connector for the SJO. It's also not very hard to find pre-fabricated lengths of SJO with a plug already moulded on the end -- just ensure it is rated to carry the current the motor draws.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is US house current and a 120VAC split phase start motor.

You also need to think about some sort of switch box. They make inline interlock switches for table saws that this can plug into.

**Amperage the motor draws?** Will be on a data plate or sticker on the motor. Need for wire sizing.

**Picture of where the cord would attach to the motor and end of motor?** I'd start with strain relief for where the cord enters the motor and can't really give you recommendations. You need it to keep the connections from being pulled apart or pulling any of the wires over sharp edges.

[image]

Since this is a repurpose of a motor that isn't double-insulated, you will need a three wire cord. NO Zip Cord! You will need the three wire type with the wires running inside a rubber tube. And I don't like wire nuts for joining to the motor wires, crimp connectors or soldered connections with three layers of heat shrink tend to be more permanent.

[image]

On the motor, the cord wires up Black to Black, White to White and Green firmly attached to the motor housing.

The plug will need to be one of the three prong replacements with strain relief clamp. Usually, three prong plugs have both blades same width, White to Silver screw, Black to Brass screw and Green to Green or ground prong.

[image]